# How to edit custom fields of emails in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Mails in outlook have a relevance-field that can be displayed as a column in the inbox. How do one set it?

Edit: More precisely, how are the values of custom e-mail-fields changed through the outlook 2007 gui? Here relevance and a custom field 'Score' is shown in my inbox, but all emails have blank values.
[image: The header-bar in my inbox, with Relevance and my custom scrore-field displayed.]

The context-menu of emails give access to "Message Options...". I was hoping the custom fields would be available there.

[image: Message options only contains the standard fields.]

Comment: I cant find relevance in Outlook 2007. Which version are you using? Perhaps post a screenshot..

Comment: Oops, I don't have enough rep to post images now. I was trying to upload the headers of my inbox in outlook 2007 with relevance displayed.

Comment: @Grastveit  Upload the image to some hosting, add a link to the image to your post.  Somebody with enough rep will edit your post and inline the the image.  (meanwhile, +1)

Comment: Now you can post the images just do it and let us see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @wizlog, here are instructions on the MSDN site on creating custom fields (Outlook 2003): [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204247(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204247%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

However, the only fields I see as default are:
Priority, Attachement, Flag, From, Subject, Received, Account, Size, Sent, To, Watch/Ignore

Would any of those help your sorting requirements?

Comment: I had also had the relevance field as default. Following the msdn-instructions I created a new field as well. However I still cannot edit the field-value through the gui. Is it only available programmatically?

Comment: The other fields are either read-only (cannot be set on mails I recieve) or have other uses (flag and category).

Comment: @Grastveit: What language is "innboks"?

Comment: @wizlog: Norwegian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I know about any "relevance column"... However, I did stumble across a (three part) [guide](http://goo.gl/krsDh) to setting up **custom fields** in Outlook.

If you think something like this **is relevant** to what your trying to do (and you aren't able to understand the steps it describes), post a comment (or edit your question), and I'll edit my answer to explain exactly what **you** need to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the MSDN documentation for [AppointmentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210899%28v=office.11%29.aspx), [TaskItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211067%28v=office.11%29.aspx), [ContactItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210907%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and there is nothing in there that references a **Relevance** property.

On that basis I can only assume it's either a custom field or something partially implemented by Microsoft (that doesn't do anything).

Answer (score -1):

Normally you'd need to create a custom form to handle your custom fields.
But solutions based on Outlook/Exchange is slow since everything is run from the client.

Very soon you'll hit the roof of how far you can push the solution.

Normally, you're better of using Shareproint as a platform.

You do however have the option of inline-editing in the view pane.
https://www.slipstick.com/tutorial/create-a-custom-field-to-mark-messages/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.